# Center two floated divs

Tags: html, css

i have a div container which contains two other divs which should be aligned next to each other. But these two, floated, divs should be in the center of the outside div. How can i do that?

Example:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/stHqI

HTML:

```
<div class="section-download clearfix">
<div class="section-download-cover">bla</div>
<div class="section-download-icon">yes</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.section-download {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.section-download-cover {
    float:left;
}

.section-download-icon {
    float: left;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you floating them left if you don't want them on the left?

Comment: Why would you float them if you want them centered? Center the content in the containing div and make sure the display for both inner divs are inline-block.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set widths on the inside divs, they won't magically align centered.  Add `width: 50%;` to each of the inside divs.

Answer (score 2):

You could set the parent to `display:inline-block`, and use `text-align:center` to center it.

Works pretty well - [**jsFiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/2WEzY/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="parent">
    <div class="float"></div>
    <div class="float"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#parent {
    display:inline-block;
    border:3px solid red;
}
.float {
    float:left;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    border:1px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want:

```
.section-download {
   margin: 0 auto;
   width: 200px;
   height: 200px;
   border: 1px solid black;
   text-align: center;
}

.section-download-cover,
.section-download-icon {
   display: inline-block;
}
```

You set the `text-align` to be centered and then make the divs be `inline-block` which makes them flow with the text and therefore pick up the the `text-align: center`

Answer (score 0):

Your question is ambiguous; but it seems to me that you're saying you want both to be aligned next to each other in the center of the outer box?

**QUOTE:**
`"which should be aligned next to each other...in the center of the outside div"`

If this is what you want, then you need to add a height and width to each of the inside boxes. Like this:

```
.section-download-cover {
    float:left;
    width: 70px;
    height: 155px;
    background: #333;
}

.section-download-icon {
    float: left;
    width: 70px;
    height: 150px;
    background: #555;
}
```

**UPDATE:** you also need to add another nested div to do what I think you're asking.
I called it `.inner-container`, and it needs to be the same width as the combined width of the two inner divs. For example, if each div is 70px wide, then the outer div needs to be exactly 140px wide.

**the CSS**

```
.inner-container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 140px;

}
```

**the HTML**

```
<body>
  <div class="section-download clearfix">
    <div class="inner-container">
      <div class="section-download-cover">
          bla
      </div>
      <div class="section-download-icon">
        yes
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

**Working jsbin:**
http://jsbin.com/OXEPERi/1/